# Edit Symfony behavior with AJAX actions

Tags: php, ajax, symfony

Assuming I have an application using a lot of AJAX requests.

Is there a way to edit Symfony behavior and autommatically call `indexAjaxAction` instead of `indexAction` when my request is AJAX made ?

I already know that I can test if a request is Ajax with the `Request::isXmlHttpRequest()` method but I want it to be autommatic (*i.e* without testing in each controllerAction).

Does a service/bundle already makes it ?

*Example :*

```
<?php 

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class FooController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction($vars)
    {
        $request = $this->getRequest();         
        if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            return $this->indexAjaxAction($vars);
        }
        // Do Stuff
    }

    public function indexAjaxAction($vars){ /* Do AJAX stuff */ }
}
```

*becomes*

```
<?php 

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class FooController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction($vars) { }
    public function indexAjaxAction($vars) { }

    // Other functions
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use a slightly modified controller resolver that would be used instead of the current controller resolver in the regular `KttpKernel::handleRaw` [process](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php#L142).

Please note that I may be wrong in my thinking here and it is untested.

The controller resolver class has the id `controller_resolver.class` which you could overwrite with your custom one in your config using

In your `app/config/config.yml`...

```
.. config stuff ..

parameters:
    controller_resolver.class: Acme\SomeBundle\Controller\ControllerResolver
```

And then in your new `ControllerResolver`...

```
namespace Acme\SomeBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\ControllerResolver
                    as BaseControllerResolver;

class ControllerResolver extends BaseControllerResolver
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc
     */
    public function getArguments(Request $request, $controller)
    {
        if (is_array($controller) && $request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            $action = preg_replace(
                '/^(.*?)Action$/', 
                '$1AjaxAction', 
                $controller[1]
            );

            try {
                $r = new \ReflectionMethod($controller[0], $action);

                return $this->doGetArguments(
                    $request, 
                    $controller, 
                    $r->getParameters()
                );
            } catch( \Exception $e) {
                // Do nothing
            }
        }

        return parent::getArguments($request, $controller);
    }
}
```

This class just extends the current controller resolver and will attempt to use the `youractionAjaxAction` if it exists in the controller and then falls back to the regular resolver if it gets an error (method not found);

Alternatively you could just use...

```
if (is_array($controller) && $request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
    $controller[1] = preg_replace(
        '/^(?P<action>.*?)Action$/', 
        '$1AjaxAction', 
        $controller[1]
    );
}

return parent::getArguments($request, $controller);
```

.. which would just update the called action and then send it through to the regular resolver with no fall back, meaning that every action that could be called using an `XmlHttpRequest` would require a corresponding AjaxAction.

Comment: +1 for your fast answer, I will try to deal with that and marked as solved if it works. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into FOSRestBundle for Symfony, it can be very useful if you have 1 action that can either return json data or rendered html template depending on the request method

Comment: +1 for that bundle, It can be useful but my question is more specific. What I am looking for does not depend on HTTP method I am using.

Comment: hi Fabien, that one will actually do the check for isAjaxRequest for you, so even with the same HTTP method, it will render differently.