# Extending Symfony2 Controller Resolver

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-components

I am currently creating a bundle which can rename fooAction into fooAjaxAction if request is an Ajax Request. 
As the answer of [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24672349/edit-symfony-behavior-with-ajax-actions) says, I have to extend the controller resolver class. 
I have a `ResourceNotFoundException` if I change the controller_resolver.class in config.yml . but if I don't, I don't have any errors (but there is no override so this is not what I want)

**My questions are : how can i register my new controller resolver and use it ? I am right ? Wrong ?**

This is what I've done :

*You can find my Bundle for testing in packagist and download it via :*

`composer require  "/prefix-bundle":"dev-dev"`

*activate it in AppKernel.php:*

```
<?php 
// AppKernel.php
new \PrefixBundle\PrefixBundle()
```

Config

```
# App/Config/config.yml
parameters:
    controller_resolver.class: PrefixBundle\Component\Controller\ControllerResolver
```

So this is my custom Controller.

```
<?php 
namespace \PrefixBundle\Component\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\ControllerControllerResolver as BaseControllerResolver;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class ControllerResolver extends BaseControllerResolver
{

    public function getArguments(Request $request, $controller)
    {
        parent::getArguments($request, $controller);
    }
}
```

I am assuming that this controller is doing nothing for instance, I will add logic in the future.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: My question is : how can i register my new controller resolver and use it ? - edited

Comment: What namespace are you using for your controller resolver? I got it wrong in my original answer but I will update now.

Comment: updated code, didn't copy the namespace

Comment: Yeah just realised and went through your github. I didn't put the `return` before `parent::getArguments` so the method is doing nothing. Not sure why the controller resolver can't be found though. or is it that controller aren't being found when using this resolver?

Comment: that was that, missign return, answer if you want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return is missing from the `getArguments` method (due to me missing it when I did the other answer) meaning that the controller resolver isn't actually getting any arguments to resolve.

```
public function getArguments(Request $request, $controller)
{
    // Should have the return..
    return parent::getArguments($request, $controller);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I have spent all night at that. Have a nice day !

Comment: I really should have gotten it right the first time, to be fair.